# Writing a Teradata With Statement in RODBC in R

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

I have connected Teradata to my R session with RODBC.

Typically I use `data <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT statement")` however when I put the following WITH statement in place of the SELECT statement, there is an error.

```
data <- sqlQuery(conn, 
"WITH zzz as (SELECT statement1),
yyy as (SELECT statement2)

SELECT statement3"
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

try correcting mismatched " and ) as below...

data <- sqlQuery(conn, 
"WITH zzz as (SELECT statement1),
yyy as (SELECT statement2)

SELECT statement3")